# Sort a binary file based on the position of bytes

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7, binaryfiles

I have a binary file with every 3 bytes together in ascending order.

For example: my binary file contains

```
00 00 01 00 00 02 00 00 03 .......
```

Every 3 bytes occur in the middle of a row with 16 bytes - for example:

```
AA BB CC DD EE FF 11 22 00 00 01 AA BB CC DD EE
```

in between each row like this, there is data for about every 256 bytes ...

```
11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 00 00 03 AA BB CC DD EE ...
```

I need to arrange the row + previous block of data based on the numbers in the middle of the row, according to my file.

Comment: the description is not quite clear. can you post your file or excerpts from it and any code that you have already.

Comment: This is how my binary file will look like.
34323439360000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
F40DB84B03196D55 A60000 800800005D

Comment: I have another binary file (call it file B) with contains all the numbers from the positions( which I have seperated above in the last line) sorted in ascending order for the whole file. Based on the first number in the file B, I need to search that number in my binary file in that exact position and copy the block of 256 bytes above it and create a new file. Again take the second number from file B search it for in binary file and copy the block of data above and append it in the new file. This should go on for all the numbers in file B by creating a new file according to the file B list.